# What does UA in BIF_UAHINT means?

Tags: windows, winapi, language-agnostic

[Here it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773205%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and i have no idea what UA in BIF_UAHINT stand for.

> BIF_UAHINT = **B**ROWSE**I**NFO **F**lag for ***WHAT HERE?*** **H**int

UA as acronym for **U**s**a**ge sounds rather wacky, and i cannot think out no better meaning than **U**ser **A**gent, which sounds ridiculous in the context too.

Comment: UA = User Accessibility.  A screen reader will speak it back.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you please convert your comment to answer? I think your idea about UA for User Accessibility (backed by screen reader activity, too) is realy worthwhile.

Comment: I looked for links to backup the answer but couldn't find any.  Go ahead and post + accept your own answer if you're comfortable with it.

Comment: It's more likely User Assistance, not User Accessibility. While the text will be read out by a screenreader - assuming the user is using one - it's also displayed on the screen as regular text, so is available to all users, so is not specific to accessibility. UA / User Assistance is tech jargon for helpfile, tooltip and similar textual content.

Comment: Glad you found a theory that you liked... Still not sure why the exact meaning of the acronym matters so much, given that the documentation is perfectly clear about the important stuff.

Comment: @CodyGray, you are confusing *theories* with *hypotheses*, and now, despite of your advice to ignore uncertainty and live as is, i've got two, one better than another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UA is often used as an acronym for User Assistance - which includes everything from end-user documentation to helpfiles to tooltips - and the text that tells a user what to do in a dialog. As an example, see the [Wikipedia - User Assistance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_assistance) page.

Comment: Bright idea! Yes, this is more logical than **A** for Accessibility. I'll let couple of days to pass for pluralism purposes and accept. Thanks!